# Facing error while installing npm in react

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npx

I want to make a react project but when I  execute `npx create-react-app`, it doesn't respond. Can anyone tell me what the issue I am facing here is? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV8jz.png).

Comment: check you node and npm versions: `node -v` and `npm -v` on my machine with: node v14.17.0 and npm 6.14.13 >> `npx create-react-app visual` works without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

make an empty folder then drag it over VSC, and type in terminal: npx create-react-app . (dot means in the current folder) also make sure u have node installed, type: node -v (to check what version u have)

Answer (score 0):

From the official [ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html):

> You’ll need to have **Node >= 14.0.0** and **npm >= 5.6** on your machine. To create a project, run:
>
> ```sh
> npx create-react-app my-app
> cd my-app
> npm start
> ```

In the screenshot you provided, you indeed ran the command; but, it doesn’t show that you checked that the directory, `visual`, was created within your working directory, `New folder`. In addition, no error message was output; so as it stands, we know the `npx` command exists; and can only *assume* that, the command executed without error.

When using `create-react-app`:

1. A new directory will be created in the **working directory** (*in your case, `New folder`*) you run the command within.
2. This new directory will have the name of the argument you provided to `create-react-app` (*in your case, `visual`*).
3. So your directory structure you look like this:

   ```
   New folder/
     └─ visual/
   ```

The issue I see is that, the general output normally seen when running `create-react-app` (*as shown [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)*) did not appear in your screenshot; however, I’ve never ran it from **MS PowerShell**, as you appear to be. So you’ll want to check:

- That you’re not overthinking this, and ensure that the, `my-app`, folder really wasn’t created;
- And that your `NodeJS` version is either `14.0.0` or higher:

  ```
  node -v
  ```
- And that `create-react-app` was **not** installed **globally**:

  - To check this, run:

    ```
    npm list -g
    ```
  - If you see `create-react-app` in the list, run:

    ```
    npm uninstall -g create-react-app
    npm install create-react-app
    ```
- Or that running it from `cmd` (*or `cygwin`*) instead of `powershell` is maybe the better option.